# Access WCF WebService from Javascript WITHOUT using ScriptManager

Tags: javascript, wcf, web-services

I am trying to expose our WCF Web service to both out WPF client and REST clients.  The WPF client side is easy since Microsoft already done all the proxy.  For REST Clients, I read a lot of examples talk about how to use ScriptManager in ASP.Net Web Form page, so that when the page arrive to client web browser, all the proxy objects for calling WCF Webservices are already there.  However, our web pages are hosting on a server DIFFERNT from the one that serves the WCF WebServices.  So the ScriptManager on ASP.Net Web Form page approach does not work for us.  Does anyone have another solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:

[jQuery AJAX calls to a WCF REST Service](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Apr/21/jQuery-AJAX-calls-to-a-WCF-REST-Service)

Quote from the article:

> In this post I'll show how you can use jQuery to call a WCF REST
>   service without requiring the ASP.NET AJAX ScriptManager and the
>   client scripts that it loads by default.